# Writing to a symbolic number of spots in a symbolic array

Tags: haskell, sbv

I have an `SArray Integer Integer` and I want to write `k` times to that array. For example, I want to call `writeArray arr 1 10`, `writeArray arr 2 10`, ..., `writeArray arr k 10`. However, I do not know how to do this when `k` itself is symbolic. Is this even possible?

I tried some things like this:

```hs
import qaulified Data.SBV as S
import qualified Data.SBV.List as S

writeBlock :: S.SArray Integer Integer -> S.SInteger -> S.SInteger -> S.SInteger -> S.SArray Integer Integer
writeBlock arr sz k v =
  let keyVals = S.zip (keyList sz k) (valueList sz v)
  in S.foldl writeArray' arr keyVals
  where
    keyList 0 _ = S.nil
    keyList size key = key S..: keyList (size - 1) (key + 1)

    valueList 0 _ = S.nil
    valueList size value = value S..: valueList (size - 1) value

    writeArray' arr (key, value) = S.writeArray arr key value
```

which fails since `SArray` is not an `SBV a`. I also tried using concrete lists, which failed with different errors. Please let me know if there is any way to do this. Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Basically no this is not possible. But if you know an upper bound on `k` (concretely, not symbolically), then you can write to all positions up to the upper bound, using `k` to decide between writing `10` and writing the old value back in.

Comment: Hmmm, ok thanks. Might be able to make do with this workaround. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

When symbolically programming, you want to be very careful with what variables are used for control and what variables are used as data. It's perfectly fine to have your data to be completely symbolic. But you want to avoid symbolic variables in your control-flow. That is, data-flow of your program can be completely symbolic, but control-path should be (mostly) concrete.

Since you're using `k` as a control-variable, any sort of recursion you do on it will fail to terminate. Think about how something like this will execute:

```hs
    valueList 0    _     = S.nil
    valueList size value = value S..: valueList (size - 1) value
```

There are two problems here: First you cannot use pattern-matching on a symbolic variable. (There's really nothing SBV can do about this, Haskell pattern-matching only works on concrete values; and for good reason.) So, the "symbolic" way of writing something like this would be:

```hs
    valueList size value = ite (size .== 0)
                               S.nil
                               (value S..: valueList (size - 1) value)
```

Unfortunately, this won't work either, because it'll fail to terminate. The `ite` construct (if-then-else) has no clue when the recursion stops, since `size` is symbolic.

One way to deal with this problem is if you know a concrete upper bound on `size`. In that case, you can use that to do a bounded-loop. This would be the preferred solution if you know, in advance, such a concrete bound.

You can see an example of using an upper bound in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv-10.3/docs/src/Documentation.SBV.Examples.CodeGeneration.GCD.html#sgcd, where this idea is used to implement GCD symbolically. Perhaps you can use a similar strategy to limit the recursion-depth, making it concretely computable.